# Magento page numbers do not show up

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have a little problem with Magento.

When I click a category I do not see any page numbers. It looks like that

```
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
```

is not giving any result.

I am running Magento 1.8 and struggling for a while with this now and I hope anyone can help me out.

I can see the amount of products on a page and I can see how many products there are in total but it won't show the page numbers.

Any help is really welcome

Comment: what is the default page size of category???

Comment: Default pagesize is 9

Comment: Did you clicked in default Magento category links or did you set a category list block somewhere else? In the second case there is additional code to add the pager.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've put it in the path your template is located in?
If you are unsure about the path I would recommend you to install the Magento extension [Advanced Template Hints (ath)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-template-hints.html).

As soon as it's installed you can put the parameter "ath=1" at the end of your URL to get the paths of all the templates which are getting loaded (for example: "http://mydummystore.com/page.html?ath=1").